# Java and Implicit Concurrency?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am looking into various features where concurrency is performed Implicitly in Java and how the JVM handles these, So far I have found streams and how they use the fork/join frame work Implicitly, I am curios on other implicit features in Java, Although the Thread pools are implicitly created is this still a Implicit concurrency feature for Java as the programmer can define certain things?Also my other question is what other Implicit concurrency features are there that I can research into.

Thanks

Comment: check NIO2 APIs, wich provides asynchronous I/O. It's a "kind of" concurrency.

Comment: Streams don't use fork'join implicitly - you generally have to call `stream.parallel()` to make them parallel.

Answer (score 0):

In the JDK, thankfully probably nowhere. As a core library, it would be shameful to spawn thread without the consent of the application.

However, when you chose to use a feature that offers concurrency, like parallel streams, ForkJoinPool and ThreadPoolExecutor, then it's quite normal.

It seems you want to know something more precise though. Digging through code to learn isn't always the best way...